Given 99 bags of red and blue sweets, is there a selection of 50 bags containing at least half of each type of sweet?
Assume you have 99 bags containing sweets of two kinds, say blue and red.
Is it always possible to pick out 50 bags such that you have at least half the total of red sweets and half the total of blue sweets. You can peek inside each bag to know what they contain.
I knows it is always possible, and I have a solution, but I'm not particularly happy with it. I remember solving it three years ago and I thought my solution was more elegant then, but I've forgotten it. I am interested to know if there are other neat solutions. Here is my solution:
Sort them in decreasing order of red sweets, then from bags numbered 2 to 99, arrange them in pairs (2,3), ..., (98,99). Then pick the ones with most blue sweets in each pair. This ensures that you end up with more than half of the total blue sweets minus the ones in bag 1, which we take anyway.
But we can also match bag 1 with the one not taken in (2,3), then the "winner" of (2,3) with the loser of (4,5) etc. And in this pairing, all the ones we selected have more red sweets than the one we don't take. Since all the bags except the winner among (98,99) are part of such a pairing and that each time we selected the one with most red sweets, we are sure to have at least half (of the total minus the number of red sweets minus the number of red sweets in the winner of (98,99), which we take anyways).
Crucially I feel like the takeaway is "If you have any (even size) collection and any matching in that collection, picking the greater value for each match ensures you pick at least half the total value".

Welcome to MSE. That question is off-topic here.

This is probably better suited for Puzzling S.E.

Pick $\lceil b/2\rceil$ of the blue and $\lceil r/2\rceil$ of red, since $b+r=99$ are of opposite parity we have $\lceil b/2\rceil + \lceil r/2\rceil = b/2+r/2+1/2=50$

What are b and r? I don't think you understood the question

I am puzzled why this is considered off-topic - it seems like a concrete mathematical question to me. I remember it from an example sheet in my first year at university, studying maths :). My solution was to first sort the bags by the number of red sweets. Pick the first bag, and from each of the pairs $(2, 3), (4, 5), (6, 7), \dotsc$, pick the bag with the most blue sweets. You can then argue that you must have taken at least as many red and as many blue sweets as you left. I also remember this problem being famous for having loads of solutions. I could probably track down some others..

Would this question be on-topic if it was changed to ask: "let $n \in \Bbb N$ and suppose we have some pairs of nonnegative integers $(r_1, b_1), (r_2, b_2), \dotsc, (r_{2n + 1}, b_{2n + 1})$. Must there always be some $I \subseteq {1, \dotsc, 2n + 1}$ with $|I| = n + 1$ such that $\sum_{i \in I} r_i \ge \sum_{i \notin I} r_i$ and $\sum_{i \in I} b_i \ge \sum_{i \notin I} b_i$?", and maybe tagged with combinatorics and a sketch of OP's solution was added?

I'm sorry but this fits perfectly within the scope which was linked to:
"What to ask here:
Mathematics Stack Exchange is for people studying mathematics at any level and professionals in related fields. We welcome questions about:

[...]
Solving mathematical puzzles."


@IzaakvanDongen FWIW I had the exact same solution as you. But I wasn't able to search for the problem by name and find any other solutions

I've edited so it looks like even less of a "puzzle". I'll vote to reopen as it seems on-topic to me now - particularly as OP's solution has been added. I'll accept it if the rest of the community disagrees, though I'd appreciate it if someone could provide some more explanation for why it's off-topic. To me this seems to indicate it's fine. I'm personally inclined to think that if it's good enough for the university of Cambridge, it's good enough for MSE!

Interesting that we had the same solution @donvmax! I actually thought this solution was quite a nice one :). I remember some other people solving it via proof by induction.

I think the general strategy is "If you can partition the set of bags so that you've chosen at least half the [color] sweets from each element of the partition, then you've chosen at least half the [color] sweets from the entire set of bags." It's clever to apply this to two different partitions for the different colors.

There are six proofs given in this blog post by László Kozma: http://lkozma.net/blog/a-puzzle-of-apples-and-oranges/ Your proof is proof #1 on the blog post.
Proof 2: Induction
We prove by induction on $n$ that among $2n-1$ bags with red and blue sweets, there exist $n$ bags with at least half the red sweets and at least half the blue sweets. The base case of $n=1$ is obvious. For $n\ge 2$, set aside two bags, $x$ and $y$, and let $U$ be the set of the remaining $2n-3$ bags. Applying the inductive hypothesis to $U$, we get a set $S$ of $n-1$ bags with at least half of the red and blue candies in $U$. Let $T=U-S$. There are now a number of cases.

Suppose that $S$ has at least as many red candies and at least as many blue candies than $T+x$. Then $S+y$ works. Similarly, if $S$ has at least as many red candies and at least as many blue candies than $T+y$, then $S+x$ works.
Otherwise, we know that $S$ is has either fewer blue candies then $T+x$, or fewer red candies than $T+x$, and the same for $T+y$.

If $S$ has fewer red candies than $T+x$ and fewer blue candies than $T+y$, then $T+x+y$ works. The same goes if $S$ has fewer red and blue candies than $T+y$.

Suppose $S$ has fewer reds then $T+x$, and $S$ has fewer reds than $T+y$. This means that $S$ has at least as many blues as $T+x$ (else we would be in the second case). Similarly, $S$ has at least as many blues as $T+y$. This means both $S+x$ and $S+y$ have at least half the blues, so whichever of $S+x$ or $S+y$ has more reds is a winning set.
An identical argument applies if $S$ has fewer blues than both $T+x$ and $T+y$.

Finally, suppose  $S$ has fewer reds than $T+x$, and fewer blues than $T+y$. Then we can use $T+x+y$ as the winning set.


Proof 3: Iterative improvement
Let $S$ be any set of $50$ bags which contains at least half of the red candies. Let $T$ be the rest of remaining bags. If $S$ has at least half the blue candies, then $S$ works, so assume that $T$ has more than half the blue candies.
Let $b$ be any bag in $S$ with the fewest blue candies in $S$. If removing $b$ from $S$ causes $S$ to no longer have at least half the red candies, then $T\cup \{b\}$ is our successful set. Otherwise, $S-\{b\}$ still has at least half the red candies. We move $b$ from $S$ to the set $T$. Then, letting $b'$ be any bag in $T\cup \{b\}$ with the most blue candies in $T\cup \{b\}$, we move $b'$ from $T\cup \{b\}$ to $S$.
Note that $b\neq b'$; if $b=b'$, this would mean every bag in $S$ had at least as many blue candies then every bag in $T$, contradicting that $T$ had more than half the blue candies. Therefore, $b'$ has more blue candies than $b$, so $S-\{b\}\cup \{b'\}$ has strictly more blue candies than $S$. Therefore, we can repeat this process with the new $S$, and continue iterating until we find a solution. The process cannot continue forever, since the number of blue candies in $S$ increases each time, and cannot increase forever. Therefore, this process stops with a successful set at some point.
Proof 6: Topology
The idea here is to realize these bags of red and blue candies as literal sets in the Euclidean plane. Then, we apply the two dimensional version of the ham sandwhich theorem to find a line dividing both the red set and blue set in half!
Here is how this works, in detail. First, draw $99$ circles in the plane, with the property that no line in the plane intersects $2$ or more circles (for example, arrange them equally spaced around a large enough circle). These represent the bags. Choose $\epsilon>0$ small enough, and for each bag with $r$ red candies and $b$ blue candies, draw $r$ red discs and $b$ blue discs of radius $\epsilon$, so these $r+b$ discs are  pairwise disjoint,  in the interior of the corresponding circle.
Let $R$ be the union of the red discs, and $B$ be the union of the blue discs. By the ham sandwhich theorem in two dimensions, there exists a line which simulaneously bisects $R$ and $B$. This line also divides the "bags" into two halves, except that there might be up to two bags which are on the line. Simply move these bags on the line over to half with fewer bags, and that half will now have $50$ bags with at least half of the red and blue candies.

I also previously asked this question on Puzzling stack exchange, and there are a couple more proofs there (some of which already appear in the blog post).
